# Maven issue with apache commons file upload

Tags: maven, apache-commons, pom.xml

I am working on a maven project which requires the apache commons file upload dependency to upload file.

Whenever i try to run the upload servlet i get the following error.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    com.java.misc.SMSSender.handleRequest(SMSSender.java:79)
    com.java.misc.SMSSender.doPost(SMSSender.java:51)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream from BaseClassLoader@1e55d39{vfs:///home/programmer72/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml}
    org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    com.java.misc.SMSSender.handleRequest(SMSSender.java:79)
    com.java.misc.SMSSender.doPost(SMSSender.java:51)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR1 logs.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>JBOSSINI</groupId>
  <artifactId>JBOSSINI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JBOSSINI</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>5.14.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-hibernate3</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-j2ee</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
      <version>8</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>trove</groupId>
      <artifactId>trove</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-beta-5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>servletapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4-20040521</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/target</directory>
    <finalName>JBOSSINI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.5</source>
              <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.5</source>
              <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/home/programmer72/JBOSSINI/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I've already checked out [JSP - File upload with Apache Commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142475/jsp-file-upload-with-apache-commons)

they too seem to have been facing a similar problem

i already have commons io in my classpath

What seems to be the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try specifying an alternate group name for `commons-io` dependency and see if that helps.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```