# How to upload File with form fields

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload file with some form field values. File upload working but I cant read form field value:

```
req.getParameter("residentId") //returns NULL
```

residentId is send to server correctly, I can see it in firebug in Net / request Post tab.

Here is my server code:

```
   @Override
public void handleRequest (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

    if (req.getMethod().equals("POST") && ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {

        Long residentId = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("residentId")); //NOT WORKING

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req);
            for (FileItem item : items) {

                String fileName = item.getName();

                File uploadedFile = new File(uploadDirStr, fileName);

                if (uploadedFile.createNewFile()) {
                    item.write(uploadedFile);

                    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
                    resp.getWriter().print(
                            "Upload success");
                    resp.flushBuffer();
                    ...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet

Comment: I posted a related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073877/how-to-use-apache-fileuppload-and-httpclient